# Matplotlib Text not taking array values

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Here is the code i tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
bb = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
cc = ["red","red","yellow","red","green","red","red","green","red","red"]
tt = ["\u2714","\u2714""\u2718","\u2714","\u2718","\u2714","\u2714","\u2718","\u2714","\u2714"]
x1=np.arange(10)
x2=np.arange(10)
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(50,70)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(331)

ax1.bar(np.arange(len(bb)), bb, color=cc,width=0.6)
text_applied = ax1.text(x1,2,tt,color=cc)

plt.show()
```

It was giving bars without any issue previously. But is not working with text. I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 596, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 310, in idle_draw
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 12, in draw
    super(FigureCanvasTkAgg, self).draw()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 433, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1475, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2607, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 706, in draw
    bbox, info, descent = textobj._get_layout(renderer)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 282, in _get_layout
    key = self.get_prop_tup(renderer=renderer)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 862, in get_prop_tup
    x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 844, in get_unitless_position
    x = float(self.convert_xunits(self._x))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Please let me know what I can do to display the texts according to the color and `x values` specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what is your expected output, but if you want to have symbols with different colors below each bar you could set them as ticks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

bb = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
cc = ["red", "red", "yellow", "red", "green", "red", "red", "green", "red", "red"]
tt = ["\u2714", "\u2714", "\u2718", "\u2714", "\u2718", "\u2714", "\u2714", "\u2718", "\u2714", "\u2714"]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.bar(range(len(bb)), bb, color=cc, width=0.6)
ax1.set_xticks(range(len(bb)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(tt)
for xtick, color in zip(ax1.get_xticklabels(), cc):
    xtick.set_color(color)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Bars with colored ticks]

Btw, note that in your code `tt` was missing a comma between the second and third elements.

Comment: That's a nice pattern putting a getter for the labels into a for loop to iteratively access properties of the listed objects it returns!

Comment: I am thankful for your edition sir. Yes the above output is what I am expecting. Just for information, May I know if I want it to change over time, do I need to clear the axes to avoid overlap or you have some thought over it

Comment: @JafferWilson You can clear the axes and draw again or you can edit the objects that you have already plotted. In general, in Matplotlib every plotting command (`plot`, `bar`, `text`, ...) returns one or more objects that can be manipulated, or you can retrieve the drawing primitives from the axes too I think (for example, if you use [`FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) this is much more efficient than clearing and redrawing on each frame).

Answer (score 6):

I don't quite get your issue. In the docs of [`plt.text()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) I can find nothing about the possibility to feed arrays of strings into the parameters:

> **Definition** : text(x, y, s, fontdict=None, withdash=False, **kwargs)
>
> Type : Function of matplotlib.pyplot module
>
> Add text to the axes.
>
> Add the text s to the axes at location x, y in data coordinates.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> x, y :
>        scalars The position to place the text. By default, this is in
>   data coordinates. The coordinate system can be changed using the
>   transform parameter.
>    s : str The text.

So I'd recommend simply

```
for x, t, c in zip(x1, tt, cc):
    ax1.text(x, 2, t, color=c)
```